# Db2 Installation Issue

Tags: db2

Hi I have tried to install DB2 9.5 in Windows 7 OS, Installation was successful but when I try to open Control Centre it's throwing an error *DB29501E* which is an error for not creating DB2 instance. How to create DB2 instance or is there a way to create while installation only.

Answer (score 0):

IBM knows about this problem and has a guide for you.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21240310